# Нужно отказаться использовать MessageHandler, clientOutBoundChannel, clientInboundChannel при websocket stomp spring boot

Tags: java, spring, websocket

Работаю юниором в одной компании. Задали задание, убрать `implements MessageHandler` в `SubProtocolWebSocketHandler` классе. И таким образом отказаться от `clientOutBoundChannel`, затем как-то отправлять сообщения клиенту. Для генерации сообщений использую - `SimpMessagingTemplate (функция convertAndSend)`.
По заданию того же начальника создала копии следующих классов у меня в проекте - `DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration, SubProtocolWebSocketHandler, WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport, StompSubProtocolHandler, WebMvcStompEndpointRegistry, WebSocketMessageBrokerStats, WebSocketTransportRegistration`.

Задание - избавление от аннотации `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker`
Помогите пожалуйста. Это вообще возможно?

Comment: Не видя код, будет сложно вам помочь. А код скорее всего вам нельзя публиковать по причине конфеденциальных правил фирмы.

Comment: На самом деле этот код не секретный пока - стандартная библиотека spring-websocket. И классы из нее

Comment: тогда вопрос не конкретизирован, вы скопировали классы из библиотеки **spring-websocket**. Хотите выкинуть от туда часть кода, и что в ошибках выводит? Что у вас именно не получилось сделать? Как вы пробовали?

Comment: Точно, вы меня поняли) Простите, редко задаю вопросы. Пыталась удалить  this.clientOutboundChannel.subscribe(this); - функция start() в SubProtocolWebSocketHandler классе. Это было глупо.  Все равно нужен канал для передачи сообщений клиенту. И MessageHandler тоже нужен

Comment: Думала как-то регистрацию брокера переписать. Конструктор этого библиотечного класса выглядит так: MessageBrokerRegistry(SubscribableChannel clientInboundChannel, MessageChannel clientOutboundChannel)

Comment: Заметила, что при отправке сообщений клиенту debugger прыгает всегда в класс ExecutorSubscribeChannel, в функцию: public boolean sendInternal(Message<?> message, long timeout) {
        Iterator var4 = this.getSubscribers().iterator();

        while(var4.hasNext()) {
            MessageHandler handler = (MessageHandler)var4.next();
            ExecutorSubscribableChannel.SendTask sendTask = new ExecutorSubscribableChannel.SendTask(message, handler);
            if (this.executor == null) {
                sendTask.run();
 } else {this.executor.execute(sendTask);} }return true; }